# Multivariate linear regression/aproximation

Tags: approximation, regression

I'm solving a problem which features a function $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4.$ I don't know the function, but I assume it's linear and it can be expressed as $ \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{x},\; \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times 4},\; \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{4}$.

I have a lot of data, ie. $ (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) $ tupples and my first thought was to perform some kind of least-squares fitting in order to obtain the matrix $ \mathbf{A} $. However, I'm not sure if this approach is correct, because I've only seen the least-squares applied to functions $ \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. If I used least-squares I'd perform the fitting for each of the $f$'s range variables separately, which I doubt is valid.

How to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: Since $y_1$ doesn't depend on the other $y_i$ in you linear model, you should be able to estimate each row of $A$ separately. Since you are minimising the sum of squares in least squares, you are minimising the sum of squares by adding each of the four sum of squares for each element.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for your comment.